# MYSQL OrderBy within imaginary(self made) groups

Tags: mysql, database

Wanted to prepare an SQL Query having a custom grop with OrderBy

Table employee

```
id| age | name |salary |
 _   _     __     ___
1 |  10 |   A  | 100$  |
 _   _     __     ___
2 |  25 |   A  | 105$  |
 _   _     __     ___
3 |  15 |   A  | 110$  |
 _   _     __     ___
4 |  22 |   A  | 150$  |
```

I want to make a imaginary group age like People from age 10-20 is GROUP2 and People from age 20-30 is GROUP1.

And Finally want to orderBy salary DESC that keeps age within the group but DESC for salary than age wise.

Result will Be Like

```
id| age | name |salary |
 _   _     __     ___
4 |  22 |   A  | 150$  |
 _   _     __     ___
2 |  25 |   A  | 105$  |
 _   _     __     ___
3 |  19 |   A  | 110$  |
 _   _     __     ___
1 |  15 |   A  | 100$  |
```

Here You See id3 has more salary than id2 but id2 depends to GROUP1 so it will come before id2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `CASE` expression:

```
order by
  case 
    when age > 20 and age <= 30 then 1
    when age > 10 and age <= 20 then 2
    ..................................
  end, 
  salary desc
```

You can add as many groups as you like and adjust their priority.

Or with boolean expressions:

```
order by
  (age > 20 and age <= 30) desc,
  (age > 10 and age <= 20) desc,
  ..................................
  salary desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6740eb03133fef7f3aab2577f5534809).
Results:

```
> id | age | name | salary
> -: | --: | :--- | -----:
>  4 |  22 | A    |    150
>  2 |  25 | A    |    105
>  3 |  19 | A    |    110
>  1 |  15 | A    |    100
```